# Split a key that is a string of numbers into single digit keys in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to turn the following dictionary:

```
dictionary = {
    4388464: ['getting']
    827862 : ['Taruma', 'Varuna']
    ...
}
```

into:

```
dictionary = {
    4: {3: {8: {8: {4: {6: {4: {'words': ['getting']}}}}}}}
    8: {2: {7: {8: {6: {2: {'words': ['Taruma', 'Varuna']}}}}}}
    ...
}
```

This will then allow me to use the dictionary like: `dictionary[8][2][7][8][6][2]['words']` instead of: `dictionary[827862]`.

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: The dictionary that I'm using is very large and I'm interested to see if this approach will make it quicker to find values in the dictionary.

Comment: tell me you're kidding.

Comment: Ohh this is embarrassing. Opening the pickled file containing the dictionary is what takes a long time! I'm still curious to see how this can be done.

Comment: Do you need a [Patricia tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406416/implementing-a-patricia-trie-for-use-as-a-dictionary)?

Comment: @Pheter if there is just *one* thing everyone should know about hash tables (dictionaries) then it's that the lookup time is completely independent of the size.

Comment: @THC4k: Thanks, I'm just getting started with data structures, algorithms, etc.

Comment: @THC4k only in the general case, with a good hash function.  In the worst case, lookups in hash tables are O(n).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import pprint

dictionary = {
    4388464: ['getting'],
    43881: ['got'],
    827862 : ['Taruma', 'Varuna'],
}

d2 = {}

def add_it(d, k, words):
    knum = int(k[0])
    if len(k) == 1:
        d[knum] = {'words': words}
    else:
        dsub = d.setdefault(knum, {})
        add_it(dsub, k[1:], words)

for k, words in dictionary.items():
    add_it(d2, list(str(k)), words)


pprint.pprint(d2)
```

prints:

```
{4: {3: {8: {8: {1: {'words': ['got']},
                 4: {6: {4: {'words': ['getting']}}}}}}},
 8: {2: {7: {8: {6: {2: {'words': ['Taruma', 'Varuna']}}}}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

A short solution to produce the dictionaries:

```
def num2dict( n, d ):
  if n < 10:
    return { n: d }
  else:
    q, r = divmod( n, 10 )
    return num2dict( q, { r: d } )

print( num2dict( 4388464, { 'words': [ 'getting' ] } ) )
```

Comment: Of course this will blow up if another entry that starts with the same digit is added to the new dictionary.

Comment: Yes, I wrote this before it became clear what the dictionaries should be used for.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a recursive defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# define a hierarchical defaultdict (of defaultdicts (of defaultdicts...))
class recursivedefaultdict(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self):
        self.default_factory = type(self)

# add an iterator recursively to create entries, sub-entries, etc.
def addToTree(it, v, accum):
    try:
        addToTree(it, v, accum[it.next()])
    except StopIteration:
        accum["words"] = v

# test it out
dictionary = { 
    4388464: ['getting'], 
    43881: ['got'], 
    827862 : ['Taruma', 'Varuna'], 
} 

d2 = recursivedefaultdict()
for k,v in dictionary.iteritems():
    addToTree(iter(str(k)), v, d2)


# use recursion again to view the results
def dumpDict(d,indent=""):
    for k,v in d.iteritems():
        if k == "words":
            print "%s- %s : %s" % (indent, k, v)
        else:
            print "%s- %s:" % (indent, k)
            dumpDict(v, indent+"  ")

dumpDict(d2)
```

Gives:

```
- 8:
  - 2:
    - 7:
      - 8:
        - 6:
          - 2:
            - words : ['Taruma', 'Varuna']
- 4:
  - 3:
    - 8:
      - 8:
        - 1:
          - words : ['got']
        - 4:
          - 6:
            - 4:
              - words : ['getting']
```

I think a recursive defaultdict is a beautiful way to create these nested dicts of unpredictable length.  (Note that there will be trouble though, if the next value we add uses 43884 as the key, as there already exists an entry for `d2[4][3][8][8][4]`.)