# python implementation of patricia tries

Tags: python, patricia-trie

Looking around for python implementations of tries just so that I can understand what they are and how they work, I came across Justin Peel's [patricia trie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406416/implementing-a-patricia-trie-for-use-as-a-dictionary/2412468#2412468) and found it very instructive: it's straightforward enough for one as new as I am to play around with it and learn from it.

However there's something I think I'm not understanding:

using Justin's class patricia() thus:

```
>>> p = patricia()
>>> words = ['foo','bar','baz']
>>> for x in words:
...     p.addWord(x)
```

I get a trie as a dictionary looking like this:

```
>>> p._d
{'b': ['a', {'r': ['', {}], 'z': ['', {}]}], 'f': ['oo', {}]}
```

addWord() and isWord() work as expected, but isPrefix() shows the following behavior which puzzles me:

```
>>> p.isPrefix('b')
True
>>> p.isPrefix('f')
True
>>> p.isPrefix('e')
False
```

good, as expected; and then

```
>>> p.isPrefix('ba')
True
```

also good, but then:

```
>>> p.isPrefix('bal')
True
```

and furthermore:

```
>>> p.isPrefix('ballance')
True
>>> p.isPrefix('ballancing act')
True
```

Something here I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the bug is in the following snippet of the code you're looking at:

```
       if w.startswith(node[0][:wlen-i],i):
            if wlen - i > len(node[0]):
                i += len(node[0])
                d = node[1]
            return True
```

it should actually be:

```
       if w.startswith(node[0][:wlen-i],i):
            if wlen - i > len(node[0]):
                i += len(node[0])
                d = node[1]
            else:
                return True
```

Comment: You're quite right, Alex. This looks like precisely the bug. I did warn that it wasn't tested very well. It was just something I scratched up and haven't really used since then. I fixed the code in my original posted answer.

Comment: Alex, Thanks very much for finding that, now it seems to work as expected. And thanks Justin for building this. Having access to the root as a dictionary I found very instructive: I think in outlines, indented text (this is the result of training in the humanities, not experience with python; however, this was exactly what drew me to python in the first place), so being able to prettyprint the trie really helped illustrate what was going on. I hope you'll post any further work you do on this: benchmark testing or whatever. I'd also love to hear any ideas on potential uses for Patricia tries.

Comment: @jjon, you're welcome!  BTW, a nice article on Radix Trees in general (with some mention of applications) is at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree